# CloudDeploy Modules with dependencies on other modules

Tags: cloud-deploy

I have searched the SE for this: I have found many examples, but none that have actually helped me to solve this problem.
   I have a set of Modules to perform specific calculations for parts of a larger problem that I want to solve. I went "modular" to aid my own understanding of the solution. Finally, I have a graphics3d section, that visualizes the complete calculations, but makes function calls to all the other modules that i have developed. I want to ColudDeploy this part and share it for a more interactive visualization. Now, there are a lot of examples on this site, and on wolfram documentation, that tell me how to do this, but the functions deployed are single line functions, or simple, self contained set of functions. I think I have done my due diligence in my searches for topics similar to mine, but I have not found any. 
   So, can anyone point me to a larger example, or the best way forward to cloud deploy a module that id dependent on other modules accessible to it in the notebook. 
   My apologies if this topic already exists in some form.
   Thanks,
   Sid.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of your set of 'modules' and graphics section you want to deploy? It would be better to not assume what is your setup because from your description it is not clear enough. p.s. does this help? [**125837**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125837/5478)

Comment: HI Kuba, thanks for the reply. Yes, your link helped. It told me that the deploy takes care of all dependencies :-) I tried it and it worked.

Comment: here it is: https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/c7b8e37b-c796-4a34-aa58-dc50b45a9ec0