# Manipulate Does not plot when accessed from Cloud

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Here is simple code - that does not plot when accessed from the Cloud. Otherwise works. Why?

```
f[x_, a_] := a*50 + x^2
g[x_, b_] := b*200 + 5*x
Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[x, a], g[x, b]}, {x, 0, 20},
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.03}],
  PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\), \
\('\)]\)(t)=50+\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(t\), \(2\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(P\), \(2\), \('\)]\)(t)=200+5t"},
  AxesLabel -> {"t (years)", "y (hundred dollars)",},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold],
  ImageSize -> Large, PlotStyle -> Thick,
  PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {LightBlue, White}}}],
 {{a, .1}, 1, 4}, {{b, .1}, 0.25, 1.5}]
```

Comment: Does it answer your question: [CloudDeploy a Manipulate with dependent functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125837/5478)?

Comment: It does not seem to me that it is about CloudDeploy - I have been running lot of examples with Manipulate that are working when accessed through QR code from Wolfram cloud. But this one still not :(

Comment: I was not clear enough, the point is the SaveDefinitions option.

Comment: Great! Great! Great! Thank you so much. It is solved! SaveDefinitions option worked! I don't understand why in other notebooks I am not using but it still plots perfectly on mobile device - but here it is only with this option that worked! Thank you so much. Greetings from Macedonia.