# StandardForm in Cloud FormFunctions

Tags: output-formatting, gui-construction, wolfram-cloud

[**Cross posted on community.wolfram.com**](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1152337)

#### Example

```
choices = {
   "label 1"                     -> 1
  , Column[{"label", 2}]         -> 2
  , Framed[3]                    -> 3
  , HoldForm @ Sum[i, {i, 0, ∞}] -> 4
};

CloudDeploy @ FormFunction[
 { "a" -> <|
     "Interpreter" -> choices
   , "Control" -> (RadioButtonBar[##, Appearance -> "Vertical"] &)|>
 }
]
```

[image]

So by default StandardForm is not supported (though e.g. `Column` is).

#### My attempts to fix it

- I tried to force `"HTMLCloudCDF"` as an export form for those elements:

  ```
   ...
   "Interpreter" -> MapAt[ExportForm[#, "HTMLCloudCDF"] &, choices, {All, 1}]
   ...
  ```

  [image]

  But it is not supported.
- At the end I am using: `ExportForm[#, "SVG"] &` but it makes fonts inconsistent with the rest of the form and selected item's label gets an ugly red frame if it is an image:

  [image]

#### Question

How to use arbitrary expressions in form functions layout? Is there a better way than SVG? Shouldn't it work out of the box?

#### Related

[Wolfram Cloud deployment guidelines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123894/5478)

Answer (score 1):

What about doing the following thing.

(1) In a text cell (Ctrl-7) just write the mathematics, that is Ctrl-( to open inline math, type the formula and Ctrl-) to close the inline math.

(2) Shift-Ctrl-E to Show Expression and copy the expression. Example below.

```
math = Cell[
  TextData[Cell[
    BoxData[FormBox[
      RowBox[{RowBox[{"F", "(", "x", ")"}], "=", 
        RowBox[{SubsuperscriptBox["\[Integral]", 
           RowBox[{"-", "\[Infinity]"}], "x"], 
          RowBox[{RowBox[{"f", "(", "\[Tau]", ")"}], 
            RowBox[{"\[DifferentialD]", "\[Tau]"}]}]}]}], 
      TraditionalForm]], FormatType -> "TraditionalForm"]], "Text"]
```

(3) Use combination of `EmbeddedHTML[]` and `ExportString[]` with `MathML` format. Example below.

```
mathml = EmbeddedHTML[ExportString[math, "MathML"]]
```

(4) Using this I produced the following form.

```
FormFunction[
 {Style["Form 1", "Title"],
  "Describtion of the form here.",
  "x" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {"A" -> 1, mathml -> 2},
    "Control" -> (RadioButtonBar[##, Appearance -> "Vertical"] &),
    "Label" -> "Select choice"|>},
 Identity,
 PageTheme -> "Blue"
 ]
```

The code above gives the following result.

[image]

This is not ideal but at least it does not have the frame around it and fonts seem to be consistent.

This answer is based on the help that I got from @b3m2a1 and @Kuba (he pointed me the this question).

Comment: +1 I will definitely use it but it won't help with more than math content, right? So e.g. `Framed[1]` will still be problematic. Either way, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

To an address your comment on Michal's post, we can actually implement the `Framed` in CSS and use that in the `FormFunction`, using the `styledXMLExport` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154142/38205):

```
$xml =
  XMLElement[
   "p",
   {},
   {
    XMLElement["framed",
     {},
     {"1"}
     ]
    }
   ];
$style =
  {
   "framed" ->
    {
     "border" -> "solid 1px black",
     "display" -> "inline-block",
     "padding" -> "5px"
     }
   };

fo =
  FormFunction[
   {
    styledXMLExport[$xml, $style]
    }
   ];
HTTPHandling`StartWebServer[fo];
"http://localhost:7000" // SystemOpen
```

Of course, just because we can doesn't mean we should have to. WRI is clearly dropping the ball here.

Comment: I know I can ([124015](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124015/5478)), but I still will be left with out general solution and uncertainty about what works and what does not. Not to mention that I'd have to manually translate all options. :(

Comment: @Kuba when I have time I'll pick through the HTML export context because my guess is a lot of this is cooked in. Or maybe we can do an HTML export sans links or something and that'll be fast enough.

Comment: Forms are typeset cloud side afaic so relevant code may not be available locally.

Comment: @Kuba Yeah I was gonna do the compilation on the deployment side. But I looked at it and there's no good support for things like Framed so ah well.