# How to align FormFunction title to centre of page?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy, form-building

I am trying to align the title of my form with the centre of the form. It does not appear to work with this:

```
    CloudDeploy@FormFunction[{"image" -> "Image"}, #img &,
  AppearanceRules -> <|
    "Title" -> 
     Column[CloudImport[
       "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/7ee639a7-12c8-44eb-b86b-\
cf3f78bad8cb"], Alignment -> Center]|>]
```

I am aware that some things do not work well with CloudDeploy forms but is there some workaround which allows me to centre the image over the input box?

Related: Is there a way to add text after the input box?

EDIT: The latter works with b3m2a1's suggestion but I can't make the centralised image work.

Best,
Max

Comment: Does this solve your issue: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154132/creating-forms-with-formfunction-with-additional-elements-before-input-fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CloudDeploy @ FormFunction[
  {"image" -> "Image"}
, #img &
, AppearanceRules -> <|
    "Title" -> EmbeddedHTML[ StringTemplate[
      "<img src=`url` style=`style`>"
    , InsertionFunction -> ToString@*InputForm
    ] @ <|
        "url" -> "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/7ee639a7-12c8-44eb-b86b-cf3f78bad8cb"
      , "style" -> "display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;width:50%;"
      |>
    ]
  |>
]
```